# PostgreSQL refusing connection

Tags: postgresql, port

I hava a PostgreSQL database on my PC. The Postgres server is running on port 5432. When I go on another PC and type in `telnet server.ip 5432`, I manage to connect. However when I try to connect using Java:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:postgresql:mydb://server.ip:5432/", "user", "pass");
```

I get the following error: `Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.` Can someone tell me what the problem might be?

**UPDATE:**

I changed the connection string to:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://server.ip:5432/mydb", "user", "pass");
```

and now I am getting the error `FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "client.ip", user "user", database "mydb", SSL off`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to config auth file `/etc/postgresql/x.x/main/pg_hba.conf`

Add these lines:

```
# TYPE DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS                   METHOD
host   all       all   my.pc.ip/Prefix-netmask   md5
```

After that restart the postgresql server:

```
# /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Comment: Hmmm. The question says, `my.pc.ip` is the IP of the server. But the server's config file must contain the IP of the remote client.

Comment: I added the remote client IP in pg_hba.conf and it worked. Thanks @A.H.

Answer (score 2):

Your JDBC connection string is wrong. The documentation says these are the allowed formats:

```
jdbc:postgresql:database
jdbc:postgresql://host/database
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
```

but **not** - as in your case:

```
Jdbc:postgresql:databse://host:port/
```

(also note the capital letter `J` in your string which is also not allowed)